# Unable to connect SSH between two Raspberries over Internet

Tags: raspbian, ssh

1. I have a raspberry at home with SSH server, RSA keys configured and port 22 open on the router.
2. I have another Raspberry Pi (client), with which I can connect to my house ONLY by LAN (with ssh from terminal and with putty from desktop).
3. Instead, I can connect to it with Putty (on Windows) and with Termux (on Android), from LAN and from INTERNET (without port forwarding problems).
4. I am unable to connect SSH from the Raspberry Pi client to the Raspberry Pi server over the INTERNET, both with domain and public IP.
5. I have tried `ssh -v -v -v pi@domain.com -p 22` and `ssh -v -v -v pi@public-ip -p 22` with result:

```
pi@raspi2:~ $ ssh -v -v -v pi@public.ip
OpenSSH_7.9p1 Raspbian-10+deb10u2, OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname public.ip is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to public.ip [public.ip] port 22.
debug1: connect to address public.ip port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host public.ip port 22: Connection timed out
pi@raspi2:~ $
```

*NOTE:* /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19 contains: `Host *`

What I can do?

Comment: What do you get with `ping <public_ip>` and with `sudo nmap -Pn -p 22 <public_ip>` from the RasPi client on internet?

Comment: Welcome, Tipoduro.  I've removed the references to SSHFS because they seem superfluous to  the problem.  As Ingo says, you should try `ping` using `public.ip`.  If that fails, then SSH is also sort of superfluous to the problem: You simply cannot reach the Pi by any means.

Comment: You should explain how you have arranged to make your home LAN accessible from outside, because by default this is usually not the case, ie., you can connect from the LAN to the internet, but not from the internet to the LAN -- that's normal.

Comment: Unless you ‘open LAN’ description throws something up, it may be worth talking to the ISP - they may block ports on their side.

Comment: Thanks for the collaboration.
The problem is the Raspberry Pi client, since I can access the server with Android and Windows (from outside LAN).
The results of the commands are:
**ping <public.ip>**
`4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 8ms rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 81.615/97.342/110.134/11.399 ms`
**sudo nmap -Pn -p 22 <public.ip>**
`Host is up.
PORT     STATE     SERVICE
22/tcp   filtered  ssh
Nmap done: 1 IP adress (1 host up) scanned in 2.51 seconds`
Do I understand that it is the Raspberry client itself that blocks outgoing port 22? How could I allow it?